# How can I transmit signals from pre-amplifiers to a laptop nearby using bluetooth?

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering, computer-hardware

I am trying to collect signals from preamplifiers (Aquarian Audio preamps, PA-4) and have them sent to a laptop nearby wirelessly, I have not found a dedicated device for this process, and the preamplifiers have BNC connector. I need suggestions and this is the specs for the pre-amplifiers that I am trying to collect the data from http://www.aquarianaudio.com/pa4.html. If anyone has been into this similar situation, I need your advice.

Comment: Did you ask this the other day? Then just delete and post again?

Comment: Yeah, I did, but It was in the wrong format, so I asked it again.!

Answer (score 1):

The output of the preamp is analog.  The computer accepts digital. You will need to use an analog to digital converter before trying to send the data via blue tooth.

Without knowing anything about it besides what it says on the web site, NewEgg has an [ADC](https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16812117304?Description=adc&cm_re=adc-_-12-117-304-_-Product) that might be what you need.  The output of the ADC is not something you can plug into your computer so you will need something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01KO1JNCA) from Amazon.

To get from the BNC output of your preamp to the ADC, you will need a BNC to RCA adapter, something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078481ZDJ) from Amazon.

That said, I think you would do better with something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000KW2YEI) device from Amazon that (the web page says) will accept analog input and run it to your computer via USB.  Sorry, you will be tripping over cables but it's a much simpler solution.